# javascript function mOver(obj) application

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouseover

Hi: I'm doing a site in wordpress and I need two pieces of code that keep giving me hard time. I know is easy but I can't make it work.

- I need to make that when mouse over (or enter) on any of three image, the image change (slide) into another image with descriptive text. How can I include the images onto this **sample** code and as per image on link bellow?

  ```
  <div onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)" style="background-color:#D94A38;width:120px;height:20px;padding:40px;">Mouse Over Me</div>

  <script>
  function mOver(obj)
  {
  obj.innerHTML="Thank You"
  }

  function mOut(obj)
  {
  obj.innerHTML="Mouse Over Me"
  }
  </script>
  ```

Mouse over change content http://www.nrgtechnologies.com.au/moreimages/plain-2.jpg

- Also very similar effect with a horizontal menu with sliding transition between 3 or 4 menu elements on mouseover as per image on link bellow.

mouse over sliding menu and content: http://www.nrgtechnologies.com.au/moreimages/plain-1.jpg

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at below script:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .slide {
            background-image: url(plain-2.jpg);
            width: 295px;
            height: 220px;
            -webkit-transition: background-position .5s ease-in-out;
        }

        .slide-1 {
            background-position: -30px -215px;
            -webkit-transition: background-position .5s ease-in-out;
        }

        .slide-2 {
            background-position: -354px -215px;
            -webkit-transition: background-position .5s ease-in-out;
        }

        .slide-3 {
            background-position: -675px -215px;
            -webkit-transition: background-position .5s ease-in-out;
        }

        .moz-over {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="images" class="slide slide-1">

    </div>
    <span onmouseover="mozOver(this)" onmouseout="mozOut(this)">slide-1</span>
    <span onmouseover="mozOver(this)" onmouseout="mozOut(this)">slide-2</span>
    <span onmouseover="mozOver(this)" onmouseout="mozOut(this)">slide-3</span>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mozOver = function(target) {
            target.className = "moz-over";
            var images = document.getElementById("images");
            images.className = "slide " + target.innerHTML;
        };

        var mozOut = function(target) {
            target.className = "";
        };

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am not sure whether is you want. I the logic is like above.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` attribute to your `div` and remove the javascript handlers:

`<div id="description"></div>`

Then add your handlers to your images instead:

`<img onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)" ... />`

Then in your functions use something like this:

```
function mOver(obj)
{
   var description = document.getElementsById("description");
   description.innerHTML="Thank You";
}

function mOut(obj)
{
   var description = document.getElementsById("description");
   description.innerHTML="Mouse Over Me";
}
```